# Get Specific Attribute from inline css

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i need to get specific attribute from inline CSS.

```
<div class="ABC" style="width: auto; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
```

from above div i need to get `transform:translate3d(0px,**222px**,0px);`after getting previous  i need to get the `**222px**` value and store in a variable  using j query how to go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can really get that style?
Neither jQuery nor `element.style` seems to return the translate value set in the CSS like that, so the next option would be to get the elements style attribute as a string, and manipulate that to get the transform style, then split that up to get the middle value:

```
var style = document.getElementsByClassName('ABC')[0].getAttribute('style');
var trans = style.split('transform').pop().split(')').shift().split(',')[1].trim();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/znp5k/1/)